# Unexepected token '=' in Safari. What could be wrong?

Tags: javascript

We found out that this monday some of our users send us screenshots with js errors, which we cant reproduce, and cant even understand what could go wrong.

These code pieces present in our project for a long time, and why now Safari thinks there is a problem we dont understand.

Here is the first one:
[image]

same here 
[image]

What can be the problem with that code? It perfectly works on PC, in Chrome and it did worked in Safari.

EDIT:

I've checked the script for syntax validation and it's all correct:
[image]

I've downloaded the file and checked the encoding - it's UTF-8.

No more ideas.

We reproduced the error in iPad, but it works fine on desktop Mac.

Comment: it might be a problem with missing `;` in previous lines

Comment: Safari might indeed implement slightly different rules for the automatic semi-colon insertion.

Comment: @pwolaq `;` is always optional, it's an empty statement. When you have line breaks, depending on the statement you've, it'll be equivalent to `;`. Commas `,` generate an expression sequence statement (Ah! Got it. Safari has different parser.)

Comment: Without recreation steps this could be literally anything

Comment: `; is always optional` - I disagree - you yourself say line breaks are not always equivalent to `;` - so, it's not **always** optional by your very words :p

Comment: If there was a recent update to Safari, I would agree with @pwolaq

Comment: @FREEZE - that's my point, `;` aren't **always** optional

Comment: the odd thing in the second picture is that there is a distinct lack of `=` in that function - I would suspect that a recent Safari update has a badly broken JS engine, or it's debugging is highlighting the wrong line

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm right, there are cases that line break isn't equivalent, e.g: `identifier [line break] ( function() {} )` That all is one statement, being a call

Comment: @FREEZE - sorry, I must misunderstand your point that `;` is always optional, except when it isn't optional

Comment: I'd argue that this is a bug in Safari.  While semicolons are best practice, they should be optional here according to JavaScript syntax.

Comment: Looking at the error, where would you "expect a `)` or `,` after a parameter?" in a function definition - neither of those lines would cause that error regardless of the lack of `;`

Comment: haha, @JaromandaX :-)

Comment: Check the encoding in the javascript file, or for special characters. The error  seems to be complaining about a paragraph mark rather than a new line or return.

Comment: @RobG how would you adise to do that? total.js is is nginx-compiled file out of ~100 separate js files. Where to look for wrong paragraph mark? And what it can look like?